# python -- find a list index by a expression instead of a constant

Tags: python, list

I got a list and I want to find the first element index by expression, for example, the list is

```
list_A = [None, None, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I want to find the index number when the 0 changes to 1 for the first time, which is `list_A[8]`?

Comment: Okay, so did you try to write code to solve the problem? If not, why not? If so, what went wrong, and what help do you need?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```py
>>> list_A = [None, None, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
>>> for index, value in enumerate(list_A):
...     if index > 0 and list_A[index - 1] == 0 and list_A[index] == 1:
...         print(index)
...         break
... 
8
>>>
```

you can read about enumerate [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Let's try to help beginners to `learn` instead of writing the homework for them?!  Besides a code without any explanation prob. is not too helpful either for OP.